# Add Header to Retrofit Requests

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a token which i save to sharedPreferences and then i get that token and pass it as an authorization to a Retrofit requests. This is my codes below which i used to add a header to my retrofit requests.

I need to add the header below:
**"Authorization" "Bearer" + token**

```
public static Retrofit getClient(String token) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();

    okClient.interceptors().add(chain -> {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return response;
    });

    okClient.interceptors().add(chain -> {
        Request original = chain.request();
        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", token)
                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    });

    okClient.interceptors().add(logging);

    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL1)
                .client(okClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

This how i send my token to the retrofit client

```
 Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getClient("Bearer" + " " +       authUser.getToken());
 APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

But unfortunately the server responds with the message **no authorization**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can send header to server without using an interceptor. Just add a field in your method declaration in your service interface like this:

```
@GET("my/orders/{id}")
Call<Order> getOrder(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                     @Path("id") int order_id);
```

Then create a `Call` object to send request as below:

```
APIService apiService= retrofit.create(APIService.class);
Call<Order> call = apiService.getOrder(token, id);
call.enqueue(/*callback*/);
```

Comment: What if you want to add same authorization header to every request?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for same:

```
String credentials = "put your token here";
final String basic = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                         .header("Authorization",basic);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a method in the BaseCaller Class for your headers like below:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
        HashMap<String, String> headerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        headerHashMap.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headerHashMap.put("time_zone_name", DateTimeHelper.getTimeZoneName());
        headerHashMap.put("gmt_offset", DateTimeHelper.getGMTOffset());
        return headerHashMap;
    }
```

Now create a method in your service class for url like :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("switch_user")
    Call<JsonObject> switchUser(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
```

Finally in your class caller class call the methods as follows :

```
call = loginService.switchUser(getHeaders(), apiParams.mHashMap);
```

This will do the needful :)